# How to make a diagram in Latex?

Tags: latex

I would like to make this diagram in latex but I don't know even how to start:[image]

Comment: Have a look at the `tikz` package

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As said in the comments, the [`tikz`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgf) package is great to do this (and about any) kind of diagram.

The following example should give you something to start with.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node (left)  at ( 0,0) {\(\overbracket[.4pt]{\underbracket[.4pt]{\Delta\Pi} \text{ and } \Delta\mu}\)};
    \node (right) at (10,0) {\(\Delta G \text{ and } \Delta T\)};
    \draw [-{>[scale=1.5]}] (right.north) to [out=150, in=30]   (left.north);
    \draw [-{>[scale=1.5]}] (-.7,-.29)    to [out=-30, in=-150] (right.south);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]